# Regarding the lighting the menorah, what is the reason why Ashkenazim follow a Sefardic Authority and vice versa

Tags: halacha, minhag, chanuka, menorah--in-temple

Concerning the lighting of the Chanukah menorah, Ashkenazim follow the Rambam, who was a Sefardic authority who says, *“Every member of a household should light their own Menorah.”*
Sefardim observe this mitzvah following the view of Tosofos ([Shabbos 21b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.21b.5?lang=bi&p2=Tosafot_on_Shabbat.21b.5.1&lang2=bi)), who say, *"Even if the household members were many, he should not light any additional Menorahs.” (and only light one)*
The Taz ([671:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.671.2?lang=he&p2=Turei_Zahav_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.671.1&lang2=he)) comments on this and says, “And this is a novelty, that Sefardim conduct themselves in accordance with Tosofos, and the Ashkenazim in accordance with the Rambam; a case that we do not find in any other instance.”

What is the reason behind this switch?

[UPDATE] Here is an interesting look at this subject [here](https://seforimblog.com/2019/12/the-history-behind-the-ashkenazi-sephardi-divide-concerning-lighting-chanukah-candles/).

Comment: It's a common misconception. Rambam doesn't say that.

Comment: How do you know that the practices are due to particular authorities, as opposed to being parallel developments?

Comment: [Rambam](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Scroll_of_Esther_and_Hanukkah.4.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says one should light a candle corresponding to every member of the household, not that every member of the household should light.

Comment: There's some theorizing that it had to do with the places that still lit at the doorway vs. places that moved inside the house, with the only viewers of the light being the inhabitants ...

Comment: The reason is because that's how the shulchan Aruch and Rema paskened respectively. The real question is why they did that

Comment: It is not universally accepted that this is what happened. While the Taz (following the Maharshal) says so, the Darchei Moshe explains that Tosafos ruling applied when people lit outdoors, but not indoors. And the Rambam himself brings the minhag to only light one menorah. The reason is unclear. It may have nothing to do with Tosafos's opinion.

Answer (score 1):

See Aruch HaShulchan 670 who answers this question.

כמה נרות מדליק? כך שנינו בשבת (כא ב): מצות חנוכה נר – איש וביתו, והמהדרין – נר לכל אחד ואחד מבני הבית. והמהדרין מן המהדרין, יום ראשון – מדליק אחת, מכאן ואילך – מוסיף והולך. ופירשו רבותינו בעלי התוספות דהמהדרין מן המהדרין לא סבירא להו כהמהדרין, להדליק לכל אחד נר אחד, דאם כן, כיון דטעמייהו שהרואה בהנרות יהיה יודע מזה כמה ימים יש בחנוכה, ואם ידליק נרות לפי מספר בני אדם שבבית – עדיין לא יתוודע לו כמה ימים עתה. ולדוגמא כשיראה ארבעה נרות – יכול להיות שבכאן איש אחד והוי יום רביעי של חנוכה, ואולי יש בכאן שני אנשים והוי יום שני, או ארבעה אנשים והוי יום ראשון. ולכן לא היו מדליקין רק נר אחד לכל בני הבית, ובשניה שני נרות, וכו'.
אבל הרמב"ם ז"ל ריש פרק רביעי כתב: כמה נרות…? כל בית ובית מדליק נר אחד… והמהדר מדליק נרות כמנין אנשי הבית… והמהדר יותר… מדליק נר לכל אחד בלילה הראשון, ומוסיף והולך…כיצד? הרי שהיו אנשי הבית עשרה אנשים – מדליק בליל ראשון עשרה נרות, ובליל שני עשרים נרות…ומנהג פשוט בכל ערינו בספרד, שיהיו כל אנשי הבית מדליקין נר אחד בלילה הראשון, ומוסיפין והולכין נר בכל לילה, עד שנמצא בליל שמיני – מדליק שמונה נרות, בין שהיו אנשי הבית מרובים, בין שהיה אדם אחד. עד כאן לשונו. ומנהג אנשי ספרד כהתוספות.
והנה בגמרא נאמרו שני טעמים על זה. האחד: כנגד ימים היוצאים. כלומר: שידעו כמה ימים יצא מחנוכה, והיום שמדליק נחשב גם כן בין היוצאים. ולטעם זה וודאי דנראה יותר דברי התוספות, דאם נדליק כפי מספר אנשי הבית – עדיין לא ידענו, כמו שכתבתי. אבל יש עוד טעם: משום מעלין בקדש. וכפי הנראה, זה הטעם הוא לפי המסקנא (מזקנים שבצידן, עיין שם). ולטעם זה לא חיישינן לדעת הימים, ולפי זה פשיטא דנראה יותר דברי הרמב"ם, שנוכל לצאת גם כמהדרים (הגר"א). ולפי זה העיקר לדינא כהרמב"ם. ויש לתמוה דהרמב"ם כשהביא מנהג ספרד להיפך: למה לא כתב שאינו כהלכה, ולמה לא מיחה בהם, כיון שאינו כפי סוגית הש"ס?(עיין לחם משנה, שהקשה גם כן כעין זה.)
ויותר נראה דטעמי הגמרא – אין חולקים זה על זה, וכמה טעמים יכול להיות על מצוה אחת. ובגמרא לא אמר דפליגי בטעם העניין, אלא בעניין מחלוקת בית שמאי ובית הלל. דבית שמאי סבירא להו: יום ראשון – שמונה, יום שני – שבעה, דפוחת והולך. ובית הלל סבירא להו: יום ראשון – אחד, יום שני – שנים, דמוסיף והולך. ובזה אומר שם דפליגי במה נחלקו בית שמאי ובית הלל. דחד אמר דבית שמאי סבירא להו דההיכר צריך על ימים הנכנסים, ובית הלל על היוצאים. וחד אמר דבית שמאי סבירא להו כפרי החג שמתמעטין, ובית הלל סבירא להו: מעלין בקדש ולא מורידין. אבל בית הלל בעצמם יוכלו לסבור שני הטעמים ביחד. (וכן הוא במסכת סופרים פרק קמא הלכה ה, עיין שם.)
אמנם גם בלא זה דברי התוספות אין מובנים, במה שאמרו דאם נדליק כפי מספר בני הבית – לא יהיה היכר. שהרי נוכל להדליק כמספר בני הבית ויהיה היכר, והיינו: שכל אחד מבני הבית ידליק במקום מיוחד, כמו שאנו עושים. ואז הרואה יהיה לו היכר כמה ימים יצא מחנוכה. אמנם גם זה אתי שפיר, דהא מעיקר הדין מדליקין בפתח הסמוך לרשות הרבים, ומצד שמאל, ובטפח הסמוך לפתח, כמו שיתבאר. ואם כן, בהכרח שכולן במקום אחד, וליכא הכירא. והנה לא בכל המקומות מדליקין בפתח הסמוך לרשות הרבים, כמו שיתבאר. וכמו אצלינו, שלא ידענו מזה ומדליקין בבית. ובכי האי גוונא גם התוספות מודים שיש לעשות כרמב"ם, וכל אחד ידליק במקום בפני עצמו, ויהיה גם היכר. ועיין בסעיף טו.
ולפי זה אתי שפיר הכל. דהתוספות כתבו זה לפי דין הגמרא, שהיו מדליקין על פתח רשות הרבים, וכן היו בני ספרד עושין. והרמב"ם: או דמיירי כשמדליק בביתו, או דאף לפי דינא דגמרא יכול לברור כרצונו, כיון דבשניהם יש מעלה וחסרון. ולכן לא גער בהם הרמב"ם בבני ספרד. והנה רבינו הבית יוסף בסעיף ב פסק כהתוספות, שזהו מנהג ספרד, וגם המגיד משנה כתב שכן היה מנהגם. ורבינו הרמ"א כתב כהרמב"ם, וזה לשונו: ויש אומרים דכל אחד מבני הבית ידליק, וכן המנהג פשוט. ויזהרו ליתן נרותיו כל אחד ואחד במקום מיוחד, כדי שיהא היכר כמה נרות מדליקין. עד כאן לשונו, וזהו כהרמב"ם. ודקדק מפורש שכל אחד יתן במקום מיוחד, דאנחנו מדליקין בבית, ובכי האי גוונא גם התוספות מודים. ונמצא דלא פליגי לדינא, אלא שנשתנה לפי מצב מקום ההדלקה. (ובזה נסתלקה תמיהת הט"ז סעיף קטן א, דלא מצינו שהאשכנזים ינהגו כהרמב"ם, והספרדים כתוספות. וכל זה מבואר בכנסת יחזקאל סימן יז. וגם הגר"א סעיף קטן ה רמיז לה, וכן עיקר. ודייק ותמצא קל.)
והנה עתה בזמנינו – חזר המנהג כדברי התוספות. שהרי הרמב"ם כתב להדליק כמנהג אנשי הבית, בין אנשים בין נשים, וכו'. עד כאן לשונו. ובוודאי כן הוא, שהרי הנשים חייבות בנר חנוכה כאנשים. ומימינו לא שמענו זה, ואפילו כשיש כמה בנים גדולים – יוצאים בהדלקת אביהם, ואפילו יש עוד אנשים. ולפרקים יש מי שמברך ומדליק בפני עצמו. ונראה לי דגם בזה יש טעם, דאנחנו הורגלנו להדליק על פתח החדר הגדול, שרוב הנכנסים והיוצאים הולכין דרך שם. אם כן הדר הוה ליה כבזמן הש"ס, שכולן צריכין להיות במקום אחד, ולא הוי הכירא. אך יותר נראה: כיון דיוצאין בין כך ובין כך – אין חוששין לזה, ויכולין לעשות כמה שירצו. ודיינו להיות מהדרין מן המהדרין, אף אם לא נהיה כמהדרין – מכל מקום ידי המצוה יצא (כן נראה לעניות דעתי).

How many candles should we light? The Talmud in Shabbat (21.2) says the following:

“ The commandment of Hanukkah is that every household light one candle. And those who wish to beautify the commandment (Mehadrin) should light one candle for each member of the household. And those who wish to beautify the commandment further (Mehadrin Min Hamehadrin) should on the first night light one candle and then go on to to add (1 per night).”
Our Rabbis the Baalei Ha’Tosaphot say that the Mehadrin Min Hamehadrin do not build upon the Mehadrin, who say to light for everyone, because (that would defeat) one of the main purposes (of the Hanukkah candles, which) is that people should see the candles and know what day of Hanukkah it is. If you were to light the Hanukkah candles depending on how many family members there are- you would have no idea what day of Chanukah it was! For example: (Lets say) someone sees four candles (in the window)… Possibility 1: There could just be one person in the house- and it was the fourth day of Chanukah. Possibility 2: It could be that there were 2 people in the house and it was the second day. Possibility 3: It could be that there are four people and it was the first day. [His message is clear: there has to be a set standard]. Therefore, we should only light one candle for the entire household one the first night, followed by two on the second night, and so on.

However, Maimonides of blessed memory in the beginning of the fourth chapter wrote:

"How many candles [does one light?] ... each and every household should light one candle ... and one who wishes to glorify [the commandment] should light candles according to the number of the members of the household ... and those who wish to glorify further ... should light a candle for everyone on the first night, and continue to add ... [one candle per night]. How is this? Were the members of the household ten men, he lights on the first night ten candles, and on the second night, twenty candles ... and the common custom in all our cities in Spain is that all members of the household light one candle on the first night, and continue to add a candle every night, until it comes out that on the eighth night each lights eight candles, whether the members of the household are many, or whether there is one man."
Until here is the quote, though it should be noted that the custom of the people of Spain is as the Tosaphot.

The Talmud brings two reasons why this is so. The first reason is to account for the days that are passing: In other words, one should know how many days of Hanukkah have passed, with the current day included in that number. This reason certainly seems closer to the position of Tosaphot, since if every member of the household lights, we would not know what day of Hanukkah it it, as I have written. But there is another reason: Because (with every passing day), the holiness (of Hanukkah) increases. This, apparently, is the final reason that the Talmud concludes with (as is evident from the account of the 'Elders of Tzidon', see there). According to this reason we are not interested in marking how many days have passed, which is certainly more in line with the Maimonides's position, that one can also follow the opinion of the Mehadrin (Vilna Goan). For this reason, we rule mainly like Maimonides. However, there is a question on Maimonides, who mentions the custom of the Sefard communities, which appear to be the opposite of his position. Why doesn’t he write that their behavior is not in accordance with the law, and why does he not protest their practice, since it is does not follow the direction of the discussion in the Talmud? (See the Lechem Mishna, who also asks similarly.)

It is therefore more probable that the Talmudic dispute is not over the reason for this mitzvah (command), for one mitzvah may have many reasons. Rather, the dispute revolves around the rulings of Beit Shamai and Beit Hillel. Beis Shammai's position is that on the first day eight are lit, followed by seven on the next, and so on. Beis Hillel's position is that one is lit on the first day, followed by two on the next, and so on. Concerning this the Talmud in Shabbos is speaking: There is a disagreement (Machloket) concerning what Beit Hillel and Beit Shamai are actually arguing about. According to the first opinion, Beit Shamai is of the opinion that (the reason why you decrease is because) you need to mark the number of days coming up. According to Beit Hillel (the reason why you decrease is because you need to mark how many) days have passed. According to the second opinion, Beit Shamai is of the opinion that (the reason why you decrease is to represent) the waning holiness of Chanukah (just as the sacrifices in the Temple on the Sukkos Festival diminished each succeeding day). According to Beit Hillel it is the reverse, one should always commemorate holiness in a manner that shows it increasing [Ma'alin Bakodesh v'Ain Moreedin]. Truthfully though, Beit Hillel could have been agreeable to both reasons offered on their behalf [marking the passing days and the increasing holiness of the Holiday, and these reasons are not mutually exclusive.

However, this is not reflected in the words of Tosaphot, which I don't understand. Tosaphot says that if we light in accordance to how many people are in the house you would not be able to tell what day of Hanukkah it is. However, you could light in accordance to the members of the household and still be able to tell what day of Hanukkah it is, if each member of the household lights in a separate place, like we do. Then, you would be able to tell how many days of Hanukkah have passed!

However, there is an answer to their words, for the preferred approach is to light the candles at the entrance of the house facing the street, on the left side, within a hands-breadth of the entrance, as we will later explain. If this is the case, then it is necessary that all of the candles be in one place, and then there is a problem of recognizing what day of Hanukkah it is.

It should be noted that it is not the case that in all locations one must light near the house's entrance facing the street, as I will explain. That is why our communities have not seen the above law in practice, as all light within their homes. In such a situation even the Tosaphits would agree that one should follow Maimonides, and each should light in his own separate place, thereby ensuring that the right day will be recognized. See further in section 15.

According to the preceding explanation all has been reconciled. The Tosafos rule as the Talmud, who lit at the entrance of their houses, and this was how the Sefard communities conducted themselves [unlike the practice quoted in Maimonides]. Maimonides was speaking of when one can only light within the house, or possibly even according to the Talmud, as he may have understood that it was allowing the option of choosing where to light, as each place has advantages and disadvantages. Therefore, he saw no reason to protest the behavior of the Sefard communities

Now it is clear that our teacher the Beis Yosef would rule in section 2 as Tosafos, since this is theSefard custom. The Magid Mishna reports as well that this was the custom in his community. The Rema, for his part, rules as Miamonides, and here is his ruling:

"There are those who say that each member of the household lights, and that indeed is the accepted custom. One should therefore be careful that each places his menorah in a different location, so that it will be clear how many lights are being lit on each night."
Until here is the quote, and it is in accordance with Miamonides. Note that he is particular that each menorah be placed in its own location, which is as our custom to light within the house, and in this way even Tosafos would approve. The result here is that there really is no dispute in law, it is just a question of how its application changes depending on the location of the menorah.

(In this way the question of the Taz in comment 1 is also resolved, as he was puzzled that we should find the Ashkenazic communities ruling as Maimonides while the Sephardic rule as Tosafos. This entire explanation can also be found in the Keneses Yechezkel, in chapter 17. The Gra hints to this as well in comment 5, and this is then the accepted explanation. Attend to the sources and this will found to be correct.)